# Is there an way to use an async value converter in reactive ui?

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

I have a viewmodel with an image property of type byte[].
I have a view with an image item of type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image
In the code behind of my view I want to bind the viewmodel image property to the view image.

The code that I have is the following:

```
this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Image2, v => v.Image.Source, async (bytes) => await ConvertAsync(bytes))
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
```

This results in the error: *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type*. The converter is the following:

```
 static async Task<BitmapImage> ConvertAsync(byte[] bytes)
    {            
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))            
        using (var randomAccessStream = stream.AsRandomAccessStream())                
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage
            {
                DecodePixelHeight = 100,
                DecodePixelWidth = 100
            };
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

Please note that using bitmapImage.SetSource and make the method syncronous is not a option because it hangs the ui thread.
If it can not be achieved using an converter what is your recommended solution? Of course I can change the type in the viewmodel but that makes is dependend on the UWP platform. Which I'd rather not have.

Comment: It's due to the Async not being supported there. You could do something like `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Image2).SelectMany(x => ConvertAsync(x)).BindTo(this, x => x.Image.Source)`

Comment: The SelectMany has Async support. You could also do `Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(ConvertAsync(X))`. You don't need Async await in these cases since you have no subsequent Async calls.

Comment: I've used the SelectMany approach. Tanks a lot. I can mark it as the solving answer to my question if you post it as an answer. If you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the Async not being supported there. You could do something like

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Image2).SelectMany(x => ConvertAsync(x)).BindTo(this, x => x.Image.Source)
```

Comment: After this solution I was able to covert the images. but the images where not visible in the UI. Do the following  to see the images. this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Image2).SelectMany(ConvertAsync).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).BindTo(this, v => v.Image.Source).DisposeWith(disposables);